# cayley transform for non-square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, gn.general-topology, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, manifolds

Hi,
I am optimizing a function over a matrix $U$, where $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $U^TU = I$. I do not want to run a constrained maximization program, since employing the constraint $U^TU = 1$ with lagrange multipliers would lead to higher time for convergence. I instead want to run simple gradient based optimization. So, I wanted to encode the orthogonality constraint into the input variable itself. What I mean by that is, for example, if
$U$ was a square matrix then by Cayley transform for a skew-symmetric matrix $A$ we have:
$U = (I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ -- and then I can use unconstrained optimization with a lower dimensionality of input variables.

So my question is whether there is an extension of the Cayley transform to non-square matrices of type $U^TU = I$ where $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

Thanks
I.J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the following slides (several pointers are in there)

[Optimization on the Stiefel manifold](http://www.inma.ucl.ac.be/~absil/Talks/GAMM_Zurich_2009-09-10_Stiefel_03.pdf)

The point is that you can directly remain on the manifold while optimizing, so no explicit "constraint enforcement" will be required.

Answer (score 4):

My Friend,
did you try the following: Fix a feasible matriz Y (Y^T*Y = I). So you can parametrize your subset by

Y = (I+A)^{-1}*(I-A)*Y_0,

where A, skew-symmetric, is now the variables.

Comment: Hi Juliano,
I used conjugate gradient on Stiefel manifolds. Your suggestion of writing any point on the Stiefel manifold as product of m x m unitary matrix with a fixed m x n Y_0 is very neat.

cheers

Answer (score 2):

Now there is a new paper about this, may be it would be useful: Cayley Transform on Stiefel manifolds,
Enrique Macías-Virgós, María José Pereira-Sáez, Daniel Tanré. [arXiv:1612.07142](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.07142)

Comment: That paper looks extremely applicable, but it is a little hard to approach. Is there any way you can help distill their result? In the Cayley Transform you parameterize with a skew-symmetric matrix and the function that produces the square orthogonal matrix is straightforward - but I'm not sure what that function looks like from this paper :(